# How to solve error in python program named: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TensorFlowLinearClassifier'

Tags: python, tensorflow

This is the code which uses tensorflow library.

```
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
from sklearn import datasets, metrics

iris = datasets.load_iris()

print iris

classifier = skflow.TensorFlowLinearClassifier(n_classes=3)

classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
score=metrics.accuracy_score(iris.target,classifier.predict(iris.data))            

print ("Accracy: %f" % score)
```

I have created a python virtual environment and installed tensorflow in it. I tried to use conda as well this results in similar error

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ how to solve this error?

Comment: skflow? What documentation are you looking at? Have you referred here? https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#LinearClassifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have changed the name to `LinearClassifier`, therefore this will work

```
classifier = skflow.LinearClassifier(n_classes=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

try using `from tensorflow.contrib.learn import TensorFlowLinearClassifier`